# Django Error: app.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am creating my custom user model for my web application
This is the code I wrote for model in model.py

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


# Create your models here.

# Custom User Manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Valid Email Address required.")

        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Valid username is Required.")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = self.get_by_natural_key(username)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username= self.get_by_natural_key(username),
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



# Custom User Model
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    _id = models.AutoField
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', max_length = 100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date-joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last-login", auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default= "teacher")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

I am also modifying the admin page to show some fields.
admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email','username', 'last_login', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    readonly_fields = ()
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'last_login', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required, login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from teacher.models import User, wreport, dreport
from chili_pili.views import home

# Create your views here.
# There are multiple functions in My view.py so I am only putting few functions as example.

def loginview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
        print (user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print (user)
            messages.success(request, "You have successfully Logged In.")
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "You have entered invalid credentials. Please try again")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'teacher/login.html')

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'teacher/report.html')

def home1(request):
    home()  
    
@login_required(login_url='login')
def admin(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'teacher/admin.html')

    else:
        messages.info(request, "You don't have permission to view admin page. Please Contact Site-Administrator for access.")
        return render(request, 'teacher/report.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def weekly(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tname1 = request.POST['tname']
        sname1 = request.POST['sname']
        date1 = request.POST['date']
        objective1 = request.POST['objective']
        tplan1 = request.POST['tplan']
        how1 = request.POST['how']
        material1 = request.POST['material']
        extra1 = request.POST['extra']

        report = wreport(tname = tname1, sname = sname1, fdate = date1, objective = objective1, tplan = tplan1, how = how1, material = material1, extra = extra1)
        report.save()

        messages.success(request, "Your report was submitted Successfully.")
    return render(request, 'teacher/weekly.html')
def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "You have Successfully Logged Out.")
    return redirect('login')
```

I am trying to create a superuser via commandline and After entering all details for superuser I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/teacher/models.py", line 33, in create_superuser
    username= self.get_by_natural_key(username),
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 45, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sahilm/Documents/Programming_Projects/Python/Chili-pili/chili_pili/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
teacher.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

I have tried to set username differently but it didn't help. I also tried deleting initial migrations and database assuming user may be present but it still gives me this error.

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Now fixed. Hope you can help me get a solution

Comment: Where does `app.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.` come from (a traceback would be _really_ helpful).

Comment: I am not able to understand traceback error so I have updated the post with Traceback Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the middle of your `User_manager` codes.

```
user = self.model(
    email = self.normalize_email(email),
    username = self.get_by_natural_key(username)
)
```

`username = self.get_by_natural_key(username)` will execute a query based on username which is not created before so it will raise a `DoesNotExist` error type. I think change this part to something like:

```
user = self.model(
    email = self.normalize_email(email),
    username = username
)
```

will solve your problem.